# Chapter title split over multiple lines (using \\). How can I avoid the splitting in the table of contents?

Tags: formatting, books, amsbook

I am working with the `amsbook` class. I need to split the long title of some chapters over multiple lines (I've done so using `\\`) How can I avoid the splitting in the Table of Content as well?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You can use the optional argument of `\chapter` without line breaks.

Comment: @Bernard No, I actually need the main title of some chapters to be split.

Comment: Maybe scoping the toc to define `\def\\{}` just for the toc.  That does not remove it from the toc, but just makes it innocuous.

Comment: That's not the point: the optional  argument is for use only in headers/footers and table of contents. You need to have a lonversion, for the chapter title itself, and a short version, without line breaks, for the rest.

Comment: Also, if perchance you use `titlesec` for chapter titles formatting, the `[newlinetotoc]` loading option does that automatically, without having to use the optional argument.

Comment: What Bernard is saying is you would want `\chapter[My Really Long Chapter Title]{My Really \\ Long Chapter \\ Title}`

Comment: @Bernard `titlesec` is not compatible with `amsbook`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AMS classes have a feature for this:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\newcommand{\breaktitle}{\for{toc}{ }\except{toc}{\\}}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Title split\breaktitle over several\breaktitle lines}

\end{document}
```

There is no problem for the running heads, because `amsbook` knows that `\\` should become a space.

[image]

Comment: @Kiok Not a very well known feature. You're welcome.